# How to calculate round on very large array of double in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, double, rounding

In C# I have an array of double (`double[]` I mean)
I want to round all values to two decimal places in C#.

One solution is to do this with `foreach()` and `Math.Round()` functions
but the array is very large (1.000.000 to 10.000.000 values)

Instead of `foreach`, is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Did a test on rounding 10.000.000 items, it took ~300 ms, so unless you have to do this operation very frequently its not to time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it in a multi-threaded way:

```
Parallel.For(0, arr.Length, i => arr[i] = Math.Round(arr[i], 2));
```

Answer (score 9):

> Instead of foreach, a more efficient solution?

Nope. Fundamentally, if you want to round all the values, you've got to round all the values. There's no magic that will make that simpler.

Of course, if you're only going to access a few of the values, you could potentially redesign your code to *lazily* round on access - or even on display - but if you really need the rounded versions of all the values, there's nothing that will make that faster than an O(n) operation.

You could do it in parallel as noted in other answers, which may well make it *faster* - but it will simultaneously be less *efficient* than a single-threaded approach. (You'll end up doing more work, because of the coordination involved - but you'll still get it done faster overall, probably.)

You haven't said anything about why you want to round these values though - usually, you should only round values at the point of display. Are you really sure you need to round them before then? What do the values represent? (If they're financial values, you should strongly consider `decimal` instead of `double`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`Parallel.Foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and thread it

While there is still an operation per item, the operations are not atomic so you can do this.

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think there is any solution which does not include some kind of loop.** You could use LINQ:

```
array = array.Select(v => Math.Round(v, 2)).ToArray();
```

but it will be even slower then your custom `for` loop, because instead of modifying the array in place, it will create new one with new values.

To make your loop faster, you can split it into parts and run simultaneously, using TPL.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution will eventually devolve into a loop. Though you may write nicely as a Linq statement:

```
rounds = mean.Select(x=>Math.Round(x,2));
```

If you have multiple processors then a potentially faster solution would be to use `Parallel.Foreach`, though you'd have to test it to see if it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
List<Double> values;
//fill list

ConcurrentBag<Double> rounded = new ConcurrentBag<Double>();

Parallel.ForEach(
  values,
  value =>
  {    
    rounded.Add(/*value rounded to 2 decimal places*/);
  });
```